# awk to split and run a calculation in command

Tags: awk

This is for my own learning, but lets say I have the below `input` file that before I run an `awk` command needs to split `$5` before the `-`.  Basically, I am summing all matching `$5` strings by using `$3-$2`, outputting the lines and the total, but without a split they are all different.  I can split the file before but I am curious if I can do everything in one `awk`.  The commandd works on a file if it is split before the `awk` is run. Thank you :).

**input**

```
chr1     955543 955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2
```

**awk**

```
awk '{split($5,a,"-"); a[1]} {c1[$a1]++; c2[$a1]+=($3-$2)} 
 END{for (e in c1) print e, c1[e], c2[e]}' input > out
```

** current output** (without the split)

```
AGRN-6 220 
AGRN-7 281
```

**desired output**

```
AGRN 2 501
```

Comment: I cannot parse your problem description. What are you expecting to happen and what happens?

Comment: The total of `$3-$2` for `ARGN` and the count of `ARGN` are outputted. However, without a `split` on `$5` in the `input` making `ARGN` non-unique the count wont work. Does this help?. Thank you :).

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to post a) an example of your input (done) b) your  expected output from that (missing) and c) your attempt so far (done). Add b)

Comment: I updated with the output. Thank you :).

Comment: Should the desired output be ARGN 1 501? 7 minus 6 looks like 1 to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I see with your script is the references to `c1[$a1]` and `c2[$a1]`.  Remember that the dollar sign is NOT an indicator of a string, you should think of it more of a selector or an array whose index are the positions of fields on the line.

So that means that `$a1` is not the value of the varliable `a1`, but rather the value in the field in the `a1` variable.  To demonstrate:

```
$ echo "one two three" | awk '{ n=2; print $n }'
```

Simply remove the extra dollar signs and you should be good to go.

Incidentally, I *don't* get the same output as you when I run the incorrect script. Instead, I get an error:

```
awk: illegal field $(), name "a1"
 input record number 1, file inp1
 source line number 1
```

I'm using BSD awk. I *don't* get the error when I run your script with GNU awk (gawk). If you'll be doing a lot of awk programming, I suggest you pick up another awk or two just to see how different implementations parse your code, when things don't run as expected.

Comment: On a GNU system I would argue that this is a useless use of `echo`, but I know you are a BSD guy .. sigh ... ;)

Comment: Heh, yep. And I don't admit it most of the time, but I use tcsh as my interactive shell.  :-D